# Waiting for shell command to execute in a makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I've been trying to learn how to use `make` and hit a roadblock that I'm assuming has more to do with process management than make.

I have the following target

```
install:
    ...
    @brew install postgres
    @pg_ctl -D data initdb
    @pg_ctl -D data start
    @createuser foo -s
```

I'm installing postgres, creating a database, starting it, then creating a user.

In this case, `createuser` continues to fail because the database hasn't started up yet.

I'm assuming what needs to happen is that I need to use `wait` to hold off on the createuser command until the database has started up, but after an hour of wrangling, I have a feeling I'm not using wait correctly with something like

```
@pg_ctl -D data start &
@wait $!
@createuser ...
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: That won't help - running in the background and then waiting for process completion is the same as just running in the foreground.  The issue is (probably) that the `pg_ctl` process returns before the DB server is actually ready to receive requests.

Comment: I think the problem is that `@pg_ctl -D data start` returns with an exit code saying the database has started but the database continues to start in the background.  I have had that problem with DB2 before.  In that case you need to wait for a certain number of seconds and then try and if it fails then wait a few more seconds and try again and so on until you have decided it is too long.

Comment: And at which point, Make is definitely *not* the right choice...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Not the right choice in the sense of getting an exit code and then having the DB continue to start up? I figured I was dealing with a non-specific start up time after monkeying around with `sleep` and varying intervals and still running into errors. -- Any resources I should be looking at to learn more about strengths/weaknesses of make (vs using a script) in this use case?

Comment: @sjhcockrell - Basically, procedural/control-flow code is not Make's strong point (you'll quickly tie yourselves in knots trying to get that to work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `-w` option to your `pg_ctl ... start` command to ensure that the command doesn't return before the database has finished starting up:

```
@pg_ctl -w -D data start
```

From the [man page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pg-ctl.html) (emphasis mine):

> -w
>   Wait for the startup or shutdown to complete. **Waiting is the default option for shutdowns, but *not startups***. When waiting for startup, pg_ctl repeatedly attempts to connect to the server. When waiting for shutdown, pg_ctl waits for the server to remove its PID file. pg_ctl returns an exit code based on the success of the startup or shutdown.

---

As for your solution attempt:

As [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) points out in a comment on the question, both `@pg_ctl -D data start` and `@pg_ctl -D data start &` followed by `@wait $!` amount to the *same*: (effectively) *synchronous* execution of the *CLI*.

The problem was that while execution of the *CLI itself* (`pg_ctl`) was *synchronous*, the *action it triggered* was not; adding `-w` fixes that.

In hindsight, your problem is unrelated to `make`.

Comment: Ah thank you. I had a feeling that something smelled like a race condition / async sort of timing when I was looking at the problem. Thanks for digging in on that --- should have read the manual a bit more carefully.